# C++ How To Manipulate Output From Game Results?

Tags: c++

I just started my C++ class 2 weeks ago at my college and we have our first homework assignments. I'm gonna copy paste the instructions first and then my code to help you understand what my professor is asking for and then show you where I am stuck.

"The program needs to calculate the number of remaining explorers after the battle and the number of extra gold pieces the player keeps after the gold pieces are divided evenly between the surviving explorers (in the above example each of the 4 surviving explorers got 187 gold pieces and the two remaining pieces that couldn't be divided evenly between the 4 explorers go to the player (quest leader))."

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      double numExplorers;
      double numLost;
      double numSurvived;
      double extraGold;

cout << "Welcome to Lost Fortune!" << endl << endl
     << "Please enter the following questions for your personalized adventure: " << endl << endl
     << "Enter the number of Explorers: " << endl;
cin  >> numExplorers;

cout << "Enter the number of Explorers Lost in Battle: " << endl << endl;
cin  >> numLost; 
numSurvived = numExplorers - numLost;
extraGold = 750 / numSurvived;


cout << "You bravely led " << numExplorers << " adventurers on a quest for gold." << endl
     << "The group fought a band of ogres and lost " << numLost << " members." << endl
     << "Only " << numSurvived << " survived." << endl << endl
     << "The party was about to give up when they stumbled upon the" << endl
     << "buried fortune of 750 gold pieces. The group split the loot evenly" << endl
     << "and as the qeust leader you kept the extra " << fixed << setprecision(1) << extraGold << " gold pieces." << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
    }
```

That is my current code. Our professor has numerous examples we need to plug our program into to test against, but I'll provide one set of the numbers. The number of explorers is 17 and the number lost is 13. That leaves 4 remaining. The 750 pieces (It is always 750 as per professor's instructions for this program) are supposed to be divided amongst the 4 players evenly leaving us with 187.5 per player.

The 0.5 * 4 players leaves us with 2 remaining pieces that can't be evenly distributed and thus we (quest leader) are supposed to keep it. How do I write a formula for this?

Comment: Basically I need help with writing a formula that will calculate the remaining pieces that can't be split evenly. Pay attention to the "extraGold = 750 / numSurvived;" and the last line before system("PAUSE");

That's where I need help.

Comment: For starters it sounds like you shouldn't be using `double` for everything - in fact it sounds like you want to have `int` (or probably even `unsigned int`) variables. And then the `extraGold` should be simply `750%numSurvived`

Comment: Something tells me that you've talked about integer division in class very recently. Don't use floating point numbers.

Comment: UnholySheep, good point on the double vs int. I actually had them set as ints and when my program wasn't working idk why I switched to double. They're set back to int now. 

I switched to 750%numSurvived and everything works! Thank you so much!

Comment: molbdnilo, yeah we went over it last week :p